# How to make API call effectively on Flutter Provider?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

There is a profile page in my Flutter app and it has REST API integration, so consume the data through an API call.

I'm using a provider for state management, so I'm keeping the attribute `propertyProvider` there which holds profile-related data and there is one method that makes API call to fetch the profile data and set the data to `profileModel` property

but the problem is that it makes API call every time I reopen the profile page because it is being called in the `InitState` function.

So, I'm wondering how to make an API call only once for the profile page, because making the API again and again when I reopen the profile page wouldn't be the right approach.

```dart
class ProfileProvider extends ChangeNotifer {
 
    ProfileModel? profileModel;

    void fetchProfileData()async{
    // make api call to profile endpoint 

    profileModel = ProfileModel.fromJson(apiData); // setting to 
    profileModel

    }

}

// UI
class profileScreen extends StatefulWidget {

    initState(){

        Provider.of<ProfileProvider>(context).fetchProfileData();
    }

}

// later display that data in the build UI using the consumer widget of the provider
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, this can be achieved this way;

```
class ProfileProvider extends ChangeNotifer {
 
    ProfileModel? profileModel;

    void fetchProfileData() async {
      if(profileModel == null)
        // make api call to profile endpoint 
        // and make json modeling stuff
      }
}
```

and call `fetchProfileData` function wherever you want. If Profile model has data there wont be any api call.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

ProfileProvider is a class that extends ChangeNotifier, enabling it to notify listeners when the profile data changes.

It contains a nullable _profileModel variable to store profile information.

```
class ProfileProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  ProfileModel? _profileModel;

  ProfileProvider();

  Future<void> fetchProfileData() async {
    await _simulateAPIFetch(); // Simulate API call

    _profileModel = ProfileModel(name: 'John Doe', email: 'john@example.com');

    notifyListeners();
  }

  ProfileModel? get profileModel => _profileModel;

  bool isProfileDataFetched() => _profileModel != null;

  Future<void> _simulateAPIFetch() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  }
}
```

The fetchProfileData() method simulates fetching profile data from an API by waiting for one second (simulated delay). It then sets the _profileModel with some sample data (name and email) and notifies any listeners that the data has been updated.

The profileModel getter returns the current profile information.

The isProfileDataFetched() method checks whether profile data has been fetched by verifying if _profileModel is not null.